# How to change AWS wordpress site to use domain name instead of IP-adress?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, domain-name

i created a 'free' account on AWS and created a web-site following this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/

I forwarded my domain from an external domain-name-registrar to the instance of my AWS site. Now by typing the domain name i get to the AWS site, but the IP address is showing, not the domain name.
Then i try to follow this guide to correct for this.
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/
(Create a record set and add A-type record with my domain), and still it shows the IP address in the address bar when visiting the page.

If i go to the WordPress site settings, i find that the site WordPressAdress/SiteAdress is given with IP, and they are greyed out so i cant change it in this menu. How can i change address bar name from IP to Site name?

[image]

Comment: The WP image was created using the 'bitnami' option, and maybe that prevents logging in as proper admin in the WP site....

Comment: I found this: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/configuration/configure-custom-domain/#connect_ssh
I will test it this evening.

Comment: You can change it from `wp-config.php` directly through ssh.

Comment: @Lamanus Do you know exactly which directory this file is supposed to be in ?

Comment: @Lamanus I found it :) Under wordpress/htdocs

Comment: Now i have tried both suggestions, and the problem remains. Why in the world should this be so hard, seems like total chaos from amazon's side, or maybe it is done purposefully, so you should use theirs domain name registrar or whatever..... !""#¤ Or, i think its a bitnami config issue, so .... whatever

Comment: have you restart your nginx or apache? Once you modify the file then you have to apply the modifications by restarting the web server. I also have bitnami wordpress server and I have done this before and working well.

Comment: Yes, i have been running reboot command from the CLI every time i change something. And the VM/Instance (?) is rebooting, as the site is unavailable just after the command.

Comment: have you set `define('WP_SITEURL','https://your.domain/');` and `define('WP_HOME','https://your.domain/');`?

Comment: yes. What do you use more spesifically? ('WP_SITEURL','https://+www+.your.domain/'); OR ('WP_SITEURL','https://your.domain/'); I have tried both though

Comment: depends on your choice but you have to specify the protocol. e.g. `http://example.com` or `https://www.example.com` if you want to add subdomain. After that, when you restart the web server, not the ec2, you can access the domain `example.com` and wordpress should be pop up when the DNS A Record or CNAME is properly set.

Comment: hm, doesnt restarting the ec2 inhernetly restart the web-server? How to restart the web-server? Anyway, i'm considereing deleting this instance and try with a fresh one, no big problem as it still is just the empty 'users blog'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was the following:

In my domain-name-registrar interface I used the "forwarding"-option to link my domain to my AWS instance.
I have now changed the configuration of my domain in my domain-name-registrar interface to use ***Type A DNS record***, and disabled the "Web-forwarding"

Today when i woke up, the A Type record was updated, and now it seems to be working.